# Re-order elements in a string array if they match another string?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, sorting

I am trying to re-order strings in an array, based on if they match a string value.

My program is getting a list of files in a directory, and then renaming and moving the files. But I need certain files with a specific name to be renamed after other files. (the files are being renamed with time stamps and are processed in that order).

Example File names:

```
File-302.txt
File-302-IAT.txt
File-303.txt
File-303-IAT.txt
File-304.txt
File-304-IAT.txt
File-305.txt
File-305-IAT.txt
```

Basically what I am trying to accomplish, is I would like to move all the files containing "-IAT" to the end if the array, so that when I loop through, the IAT files are processed after their non "IAT" partner file.

Here is my code but theres not much to it:

```
string[] outFiles = Directory.GetFiles(workingDir);

for (int i = 0; i <= outFiles.Length - 1; i++
{
    //code to rename the file in the array
}
```

Comment: have you executed a simple google search on how to order a string array
for example type this in the google search `C# stackoverflow how to order an array of strings`

Comment: You can put those files after the others with `outFiles.Where(f => !f.Contains("-IAT")).Concat(outFiles.Where(f => f.Contains("-IAT"))` but apart from that you haven't said what order you want the results in - you mention they are processed in order of timestamp?

Comment: @stuartd that should be an answer in my opinion. I was going to add that myself but you beated me

Comment: @MethodMan, roger, however I just didn't see an example that quite suited what I needed, most of what I could find just was some prebuilt .net code on sorting alphabetically, which is not necessarily what I need. Also im still somwhat of a noob -obviously.

Comment: @stuartd - Thanks. Honestly the order itself isn't really that important, as long as the IAT file is processed after the respective non IAT file. That's why I figured it would be easier just to shove all of them at the end, regardless of the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom `IComparer<string>` implementing your sorting rule:

```
class IatEqualityComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string a, string b)
    {
        if (a == b)
            return 0;
        var aWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(a);
        var bWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(b);
        var aIsIat = aWithoutExtension.EndsWith("IAT", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        var bIsIat = bWithoutExtension.EndsWith("IAT", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (aIsIat && !bIsIat)
            return 1;
        if (!aIsIat && bIsIat)
            return -1;
        return a.CompareTo(b);
    }
}
```

(In Windows file names are not case sensitive so you have to be very careful when you look for a specific pattern like `IAT` in a file name. It will almost always work as expected except for that one time in production where the file ended with `iat` and not `IAT`...)

You can then sort an array using `Array.Sort`:

```
Array.Sort(outFiles, new IatEqualityComparer());
```

This will sort the array in place. The result is:

```
File-302.txt
File-303.txt
File-304.txt
File-305.txt
File-302-IAT.txt
File-303-IAT.txt
File-304-IAT.txt
File-305-IAT.txt
```

The `IComparer<string>` can also be used when sorting lists in place and with LINQ `OrderBy`.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you project your items into a new sequence with two different ordering fields, you can then use LINQ to sort the projection accordingly, then extract the file name from the resulting sequence:

```
outFiles
    .Select(fn => new{
        order = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn).EndsWith("-IAT") ? 1 : 0,
        fn
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.order)
    .ThenBy(x => x.fn)
    .Select(x => x.fn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what I ended up doing was just a simple bubble sort, as the amount of files i am dealing with is very small. I changed from storing the files in an array to a list.

```
List<string> outFiles = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(workingDir));
bool noSort;

do
{
    noSort = true;
    for (int i = 0; i <= outFiles.Count - 2; i++)
    {
        if (outFiles[i].EndsWith("IAT.TXT"))
        {
            if (!outFiles[i + 1].EndsWith("IAT.TXT"))
            {
                string temp = outFiles[i + 1];
                outFiles[i + 1] = outFiles[i];
                outFiles[i] = temp;
                noSort = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
while (noSort == false);
```